# Liquibase : link main yaml changelog from test

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I want to link yaml database creation rules from src/main/resources.. in src/test/resources and add one more chagngelog with sample data.

src\test\resources\db\changelog\db.changelog-master.yaml :

```
databaseChangeLog:
- include:
    file: ../../main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
- include:
    file: db/changelog/marketplace/sampleData.yaml
```

But it doesn't work. So, the error is : Error parsing ../../main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml

Is there any other options to link main resources from main? 
This is a spring boot project.

Error stack trace :

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error parsing classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
at liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:84)
at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:217)
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190)
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
at
```

...

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [../../main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:195)
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase$SpringResourceOpener.getResourcesAsStream(SpringLiquibase.java:504)
at liquibase.util.StreamUtil.singleInputStream(StreamUtil.java:186)
at liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:27)
... 52 more
```

Comment: `Error parsing...`. I bet there will be narrowed message about what exactly cannot be parsed.

Comment: @luboskrnac added error trace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to name changelog file located in test path differently, because during test, `main`/`test` paths are merged into one relative path for the test suite run. I suspect Liquibase thinks that you are trying to include same file recursively.

Just rename your `db.changelog-master.yaml` under test path to `db.changelog-master-test.yaml`

Comment: ok, it's working now, but the problem that it starts with files from test, and then i get an exception, cause there are no tables, which will create in main

Answer (score 1):

Give the full path instead of `../../main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml` compiler is not able to parse the path in .. format.

Below is enough to load file if the file is present in classpath otherwise give full project context path.

```
db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
```

Comment: I couldn't just hard code the full path of my system, it makes no sence. And it's not in the classpath

Comment: here full path is not system path it is project context path.

Answer (score 1):

We include SQL files this way:

```
  - sqlFile:
      encoding: utf8
      path: /db/changelog/schema/schema.sql
```

So try to add slash at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

In my occasion path from the source root worked as expected.